# Flatten a sequence of sequences (of sequences)

Tags: c++, boost, boost-fusion

I'm using boost::fusion.

Lets say I have something like the following:

```
make_vector(1, make_vector('b', 3, make_vector(4, 5.5), "six"), 7, 8)
```

I want to produce an function f such that

```
f(make_vector(1, make_vector('b', 3, make_vector(4, 5.5), "six"), 7, 8)) 
-> [1, 'b', 3, 4, 5.5, "six", 7, 8]
```

i.e. a flattened version of the sequence.

I don't mind if this is a view of the original sequence or an actual vector.

I don't mind a solution in C++0x if it can compile on GCC 4.5.1.

*Note:*

Whilst I'd prefer not to restrict the data elements, if it helps, feel free to require that the "data" elements all derive from a common base class.

i.e.

```
class DataBase {}

template <class T>
class Data : public DataBase
{
public:
  Data(const T& x) : m_x(x)
  T m_x;
}

template <class T>
T make_data(const T& x) { return Data<T>(x); }
```

Then

```
make_vector(
  make_data(1), 
  make_vector(
    make_data('b'), 
    make_data(3), 
    make_vector(
      make_data(4), 
      make_data(5.5)
    ), 
    make_data("six")
  ), 
  make_data(7), 
  make_data(8)
)
```

I figure then you can work out what the data elements are by using "is_base_of".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is one possible solution, that uses [`join`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/algorithm/transformation/functions/join.html) recursively. Basically, it does the following (in pseudo-Haskell):

```
flatten []     = []
flatten x      = [x]
flatten (x:xs) = flatten x ++ flatten xs
```

Recursively, the flattened head is concatenated to the flattened tail.

This solution is very likely not the most efficient one since it constructs many views, even for single values; a better approach could be passing the resulting sequence as a parameter in recursive calls and directly add the individual elements in it, perhaps using [`fold`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/algorithm/iteration/functions/fold.html).

Here is the code (disclaimer: I wrote this quite quickly, so the code could be filled with bugs and/or non-idiomatic ways of doing things):

```
namespace result_of
{
    template < typename Begin, typename End, class Enable = void >
    struct flatten_impl
    {
        typedef boost::fusion::single_view< typename 
            boost::fusion::result_of::value_of< Begin >::type 
        > flattenedHeadSequence;

        typedef typename 
            flatten_impl< typename
                boost::fusion::result_of::next< Begin >::type,
                End
            >::type flattenedTailSequence;

        typedef typename boost::fusion::result_of::join< const flattenedHeadSequence, const flattenedTailSequence >::type type;
    };


    template < typename Begin, typename End >
    struct flatten_impl< 
        Begin, 
        End, typename
        boost::enable_if< 
            boost::fusion::traits::is_sequence< typename
                boost::fusion::result_of::value_of< Begin >::type
            >
        >::type 
    >
    {
        typedef typename boost::fusion::result_of::value_of< Begin >::type headSequence;
        typedef typename 
            flatten_impl< typename
                boost::fusion::result_of::begin< headSequence >::type, typename
                boost::fusion::result_of::end< headSequence >::type 
            >::type flattenedHeadSequence;

        typedef typename 
            flatten_impl< typename
                boost::fusion::result_of::next< Begin >::type,
                End
            >::type flattenedTailSequence;

        typedef typename boost::fusion::result_of::join< const flattenedHeadSequence, const flattenedTailSequence >::type type;
    };


    template < typename End, typename Enable >
    struct flatten_impl< End, End, Enable >
    {
        typedef boost::fusion::vector< > type;
    };


    template < typename Sequence >
    struct flatten
    {
        typedef typename 
            flatten_impl< typename 
                boost::fusion::result_of::begin< Sequence >::type, typename 
                boost::fusion::result_of::end< Sequence >::type 
            >::type type;
    };    
}


template < typename Begin, typename End >
typename result_of::flatten_impl< Begin, End >::type 
flatten_impl( 
    const Begin & begin, 
    const End & end, typename 
    boost::disable_if<
        boost::fusion::traits::is_sequence< typename
            boost::fusion::result_of::value_of< Begin >::type
        >
    >::type * dummy = 0 )
{
    typedef result_of::flatten_impl< Begin, End > traits;
    typedef typename traits::flattenedHeadSequence headSequence;
    typedef typename traits::flattenedTailSequence tailSequence;

    return boost::fusion::join( 
        headSequence( boost::fusion::deref( begin ) ),
        flatten_impl( boost::fusion::next( begin ), end ) );
}


template < typename Begin, typename End >
typename result_of::flatten_impl< Begin, End >::type 
flatten_impl( 
    const Begin & begin, 
    const End & end, typename 
    boost::enable_if<
        boost::fusion::traits::is_sequence< typename
            boost::fusion::result_of::value_of< Begin >::type
        >
    >::type * dummy = 0 )
{
    typedef result_of::flatten_impl< Begin, End > traits;
    typedef typename traits::flattenedHeadSequence headSequence;
    typedef typename traits::flattenedTailSequence tailSequence;

    typedef typename boost::fusion::result_of::value_of< Begin >::type headType;

    const headType & head = boost::fusion::deref( begin );

    return boost::fusion::join(
        flatten_impl( boost::fusion::begin( head ), boost::fusion::end( head ) ),
        flatten_impl( boost::fusion::next( begin ), end ) );
}


template < typename End >
typename result_of::flatten_impl< End, End >::type
flatten_impl( const End &, const End &)
{
    return boost::fusion::make_vector( );
}


template < typename Sequence >
typename result_of::flatten< Sequence >::type 
flatten( const Sequence & seq )
{
    return flatten_impl( boost::fusion::begin( seq ), boost::fusion::end( seq ) );
}
```

Comment: WOW! Thanks, I'll try this and have a closer look. This looks a lot like some of the boost source code I was looking through. I was also basing my idea from the Haskell version, but I couldn't get the enable_if's right without compile errors.